# cors issue in nginx, sails and socket Io

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, sails.js

I am having a Sails Application where I use socket IO for notifying the client on some events. I am having nginx as proxy server so that whenever a request is having `/node/anything` it redirects to `localhost:3000/anything`.

consider the following as the code inside a controller which simply emits/blasts a socket event

```
getData: async (req, res) => {
    let jobName = req.params.jobName || '';

    if(!jobName || !jobName.trim()) {
      return res.negotiate({ error: "Please provide a job name" });
    }

    try {
      let builds = await getAllData(jobName);
      let result = {
        total : builds.length || 0,
        items : builds
      };

      // This is the part that emits an event
      sails.sockets.blast('message', { message: 'Server returns all the builds' });

      return res.json(result);
    } catch(error) {
      let custErrMsg = `Request Parameter: Job Name = ${ req.param('jobName') }`;
      let errMsg = ErrorService.getErrMsg(error, custErrMsg);
      return res.negotiate({ error: errMsg });
    }
  }
```

Now the client can listen for that even.
`/node is the name of upstream set in the nginx config please see below. The script is being loaded inside the index.html from the server(API application). Both the client and API runs on same domain (127.0.0.1) but API runs on 3000 port and client side app runs on 8080 where Jenkins server is running. And Index.html is served from /var/lib/userContent/jenkins/clientApp directory`

```
//index.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Jobs</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      io.sails.url = '//localhost:3000'; //works
      <!-- io.sails.url = '/node; --> // doesn't
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

The script tags has a reference to  socket.io file that resides inside my API application So `io.sails.url = '//localhost:3000'` works fine because the server is running on 3000 and but when I change it to `io.sails.url = '/node'` it doesn't work.

I have the following configuration in my nginx.conf

```
 upstream node {
            server localhost:3000;
    }

location /node/ {

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_pass http://node/;
}
```

The error I am getting looks like following

> http://127.0.0.1/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.13.8&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8UlgQT 404 (Not Found)

Any pointer/help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your client app runs on localhost:8080, so setting your path to '/node' will actually request localhost:8080/node and will not find anything, because your API server is running on port 3000, not on port 8080. However, when you specify localhost:3000, that is where your server is and it is working. So you should add

```
listen 8080;
```

to your nginx configuration in order to intercept the localhost:8080/node request, which then will redirect to localhost:3000. In other words, your nginx is not working, because it doesn't listen on the right port.

However, if you do this, probably your jenkins server will not work. So I suggest you make two configurations in your nginx - both will have to listen to port 80, however location / will have to redirect to localhost:8080, and location /node will have to redirect to localhost:3000. Then your code should work.